# How does Bootstrap hide the modal?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Does bootstrap it use Javascript for this? Like, the HTML is loaded first and then JS code analyzes the attributes of my bootstrap modal, and adds functionality to this (fade in, fade out etc.)? Is it included in bootstrap.js somewhere?

I know it fires some events for instance, so they have to be defined in the source code of Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It use Javascript Frame work [Jquery](https://jquery.com/) for all action. Bootstrap.js uses the jquery and show the modal.

It uses the HTML5 [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) to call call the modal.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

All the action happen in bootstrap is due to following files. All class you can find in 'bootstrap.min.css'

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I hope thats what you ar lookin for.

Comment: In the HTML5 data attribute link you provied, there's given a way to access the custom attributes (by using .dataset). I can't find any usage of '.dataset' in bootstrap.js though.. so how does it access them is the question.

Comment: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/all-you-need-to-know-about-the-html5-data-attribute--webdesign-9642

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can search the following code from [boostrap/modal.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js)

For example,

```
 $(document).on('click.bs.modal.data-api', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function (e) {
    var $this   = $(this)
    var href    = $this.attr('href')
    var $target = $($this.attr('data-target') || (href && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, ''))) // strip for ie7
    var option  = $target.data('bs.modal') ? 'toggle' : $.extend({ remote: !/#/.test(href) && href }, $target.data(), $this.data())

    if ($this.is('a')) e.preventDefault()

    $target.one('show.bs.modal', function (showEvent) {
      if (showEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return // only register focus restorer if modal will actually get shown
      $target.one('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $this.is(':visible') && $this.trigger('focus')
      })
    })
    Plugin.call($target, option, this)
  })
```